# Store functions in hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I know that in Ruby you can create hash maps like this:

```
hash = {"name"=>"John"}
```

But is it possible to have a hash map of methods:

```
hash = {"v"=> show_version}
```

and when calling `hash["v"]` either to execute the `show_version` function, or to return some kind on pointer that passed to some special method, to execute the function from the hash?

What I am trying to achieve, is to have a hash map of methods, instead of using a `case/when` construction, as it looks too verbose to me.

Comment: `hash = { :v => lambda { puts 'called'; }}` and/or `hash = { :v => self.class.instance_method(:method_name)}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not exactly like this, no. You need to get a hold of the `Method` proxy object for the method and store that in the `Hash`:

```
hash = { 'v' => method(:show_version) }
```

And you need to `call` the `Method` object:

```
hash['v'].()
```

`Method` duck-types `Proc`, so you could even store simple `Proc`s alongside `Method`s in the `Hash` and there would be no need to distinguish between them, because both of them are called the same way:

```
hash['h'] = -> { puts 'Hello' }
hash['h'].()
# Hello
```

Comment: besides, you can pass an argument of the next way
`hash['h'] = -> (param) { puts "hello #{param}" }`
`hash['hello'].('world') `
`#hello world`

Comment: To pass a param you simply add it inside () like this:
```hash['h'].('11')```

And of course the method will have to be like this:
```show_version(number)
  puts "Version #{number}"
end```