# Ruby: (If possible) How can I build a case statement in a while loop while the program executes to build menu methods?

Tags: ruby

First question ever,

I recently discovered TTY, specifically TTY-prompt and I would like to know if there is a way I can get my program to build Ruby code as it operates, the goal being to make tty-prompt menus on the fly and keep things as DRY as possible.

So far I have a prompt select method:

```rb
def menu_selection(menu_name, menu_options)
    return $prompt.select(menu_name, menu_options)
end
```

That gets fed these predefined values:

```rb
main_menu_name = "Main menu:"
main_menu_options = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4", "Exit"]
```

Into this predefined menu:

```rb
selection = ""
while selection != "Exit"
    system "clear"
    selection = menu_selection(main_menu_name, main_menu_options)
    case selection
    when "Option 1"
        # code
    when "Option 2"
        # code
    when "Option 3"
        # code
    when "Option 4"
        # code
    end
end
```

In my code I have about 6 of these predefined menus above, is there a way to build these menus as they are needed with when's generated depending on the main_menu_options array.length and the elements fed into the when's using variables?

Basically something like this:

```rb
def menu_builder
    # *Edits below*
    # Builds selection variable with empty string
    # Builds while loop with condition
    # Builds Case Statement
    # n = 1
    # while n < main_menu_options.length do |index|
    #    Build when_n with index_n
    #    n += 1
end

# Method above builds menu code below (Doesn't have to be a method if something else works
selection = ""
while selection != "Exit"
    system "clear"
    selection = menu_selection(main_menu_name, main_menu_options)
    case selection
    when_1 option_1
        # code
    when_2 option_2
        # code
    (...) # Continues to build when's and variables
        # code
    when_n option_n
        # code
    end
end
```

Any feedback/criticism appreciated and if I've posted something incorrectly please let me know, cheers.

Comment: You can't build a `case/when` like this, no (not without `eval`). But you also don't need to. You can accomplish the same thing with other means (a loop, a proc in a hash table, or something else, depending on what actually you want to do)

Comment: Use Dir.glob and array indexing to pass file names to methods.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs: filenames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above by @Sergio Tulentsev you can't accomplish that on `ruby (until now 2.7)`, but you can attack this issue with another approach I think that the best fit for your problem is to create a `hash of functions`, something like:

```rb
menu_options = {}
menu_options[:option_1] = method(:code_for_option1) #storage the function called code_for_option1 inside the hash
menu_options[:option_1].()
```

Then if you need to have a new option you just need to add it to the hash with the function associated.
Also, you may found this answer useful [storage functions in a hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645773/store-functions-in-hash)
Hope the above helps!

Comment: Appreciate the input! Ill do some research into this method.

Comment: Happy to help @Gibs, if works for you please mark it as accepted 

Answer (score 0):

### Build and Present Menus Without Metaprogramming

A useful approach is to approximate the *behavior* of Bash's `select` command to build your menus. For example, if you want to perform some operation on a list of files, you can use [Dir#glob](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Dir.html#method-c-glob) to build your menu and access the user's selection. Using Ruby 2.7.2:

```rb
# this will hold your menu options
options = {}

# populate menu with files to select, or
# with whatever else you may want
Dir.glob(?*).each_with_index do |file, idx|
  options[idx] = file
end
#=> {0=>"bar", 1=>"baz", 2=>"foo"}

# present menu and prompt
options.each { |key, val| printf "%d) %s\n", key, val }
print 'Selection: '
selection = Integer(gets)
#=> 2

# value to pass to method or case statement
selected = options[selection]
#=> "foo"
```

If you're not dealing with files, you can still use a similar approach to map your menu options to a Hash or Array containing method names, procs, or whatever else you might imagine. Since hashes and arrays *can* be built at runtime, this reduces the problem to one of presentation and selection via key or index, rather than metaprogramming.

You can then invoke whatever action you like using any combination of *selection*, *selected*, and *options*. Any branching you need to do based on *selected* could then be done on a menu-specific case statement, rather than trying to build a case statement dynamically without resorting to [Kernel#eval](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Kernel.html#method-i-eval).

Comment: Cheers for the input! Ill see if I can implement this in the way I'd like and see how I go.